# How to make bar graph segments cross-filterable

Tags: apache-superset

With this simple dashboard, the donut chart and bar chart are showing the same data.  The difference in values is much easier to see on the bar graph, so I'd like to use that for this type of data.  However, clicking the bars doesn't do cross-filtering... it seems as if all the bars are considered one series so nothing gets filtered out.

The right (bar2) chart is almost what I'm looking for.  It's missing the labels and hovering shows a tooltip with all 5 values, not just one.  To get this effect, I changed the x-axis to custom sql: 'data' and moved `letter` to the dimensions.

By contrast, the donut chart is the best of both worlds: it shows the same 5 segments and clicking any of them does cross-filtering as you'd expect; each segment is properly labeled and hovering shows the value of that segment.  The only down side here is that shape isn't well-suited to visualizing differences in this dataset.

**Question**: how can I make a bar graph of this data where each bar is colored and can emit cross-filters (right bar2) and has a label under it (left bar)?

[image]